# Compute the map $H^*(CP^n; \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^*(CP^n, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to solve problem 3.2.6 in Hatcher. The problem is stated:

Use cup products to compute the map  $H^*(CP^n; \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^*(CP^n, \mathbb{Z})$ induced by the map $CP^n \rightarrow CP^n$ that is a quotient of the map $C^{n+1} \rightarrow C^{n+1}$ raising each coordinate to the $d^{th}$ powder, $(z_0, ..., z_n) \rightarrow (z_0^d, ... , z_n^d)$, for a fixed integer $d > 0$. First do the case $n = 1$.

I'm guessing this is going to be some sort of induction proof after I calculate the $n = 1$ case? But I'm not sure how to do that. So if that's true could someone possibly help me with the $n = 1$ case and I could probably figure it out from there?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Le $f:P^n\to P^n$ be the map you describe and let $f^*:H^*(P^n)\to H^*(P^n)$ be the induced map on cohomology. Since $f^*$ is a map of *rings* and $H^*(P^n)$ is generated as a ring by its degree two component, it is enough to describe $f^2:H^2(P^n)\to H^2(P^n)$.

Moreover, $H^2(P^n)$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module or rank $1$, generated by one class $\alpha\in H^2(P^n)$ which can be described quite explicitly (for example, using the usual CW structure on $P^n$ with one cell in each even dimension (and this CW structure happens to play very nicely with our map)), so it is enough to compute $f^*(\alpha)$.

Can you do that?

Comment: I'm unsure by what the problem statement means when it says we're dealing with the quotient of the given map.

Comment: There is a map $(x_0,\dots)\in\mathbb C^n\mapsto(x_0^d,\dots)\in\mathbb C^n$, and it induces a map $P^n\to P^n$ by passing to the quotient by the usual equivalence relation on $\mathbb C^n\setminus0$ used to construct $P^n$.

Comment: How do I begin computing that map applied to $\alpha$ I think I follow your line of reasoning until we hit the second half of your first sentence in the second paragraph.

Comment: Can you do it when $n=1$?

Comment: No, I'm unsure what you mean by describing the generator $\alpha$ using the cw structure on $P^n$.

Comment: Do you know the cohomology of $P^n$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ for $H^i$ with $i$ even and $0 \leq i \leq 2n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: And *how* did you compute that? When you did that, you must have exhibited a generator of $H^2$ is one way or another.

Comment: Since I know there's only cells in even dimensions, I know I have chain complex structure $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \ldots$ where all the maps are $0$.

Comment: Well, those Z are certain relative chomology groups coming from the cw structure. If you trace the whole computation, you can be very explicit about a generator.

Comment: It's generated by the cell in that dimension?

Comment: We have the cochain complexes from the duals of the chain complex on $P^n$ but the homology groups of $P^n$ are generated by the cells in even dimensions. Therefore all of the duals are either $0$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ still unsure on what you mean about the generator.

Comment: I think you should talk in person to someone. This is way to messy to explain.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your help.